# Finding out what happened to German prisoner of world war 2?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, imprisonment

My mother was a Dutch prisoner of war in Mauthausen in 1945. She managed to save the life of a German POW, who was already 11 years in the camp by that time.

He fell in love with my mother and wrote her a number of love letters, both from Mauthausen and later from Victoriastrasse in Munchen.

His name was Franz Joseph Gebele. I would like to return the letters to any family there may still be if they are interested.

How can I find out what happened to F.J. Gebele or his family?

Comment: The phone book of Munich lists five families of that last name - as he apparently was set free is is just like any random search for a person.